# Spinner setOnItemSelectedListener doesn't call onItemSelected

Tags: android, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

In the last few days I tried to insert some spinner inside some cells of a table where the headers on the top and on the left are fix and only the other cells are scrollable as a unit. To implement this I found [InQBarna/TableFixHeaders](https://github.com/InQBarna/TableFixHeaders) and changed the SampleTableAdapter.java to show spinner in some of the cells (not inside the header).

To work with the made selections of the spinners I added as usual an OnItemSelectedListener for every spinner with the following code:

```
    final Spinner aufgabe = (Spinner) view.findViewById(android.R.id.custom);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ArbeitAnzeigen.allePunkte.get(column - 2));
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    aufgabe.setAdapter(adapter);

    aufgabe.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG,"onItemSelected()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
            Log.d(TAG,"onNothingSelected()");
        }
    });
```

But all of the OnItemSelectedListener don't work. They're called once the views are created, but there's no reaction, when one item (not only the preselected) of the spinners is selected.

Here are some information to the context of my app: The table with the spinner is placed inside a fragment. This fragment is part of an other fragment with tabhost. My app has a navigation drawer to select the wanted fragment. And the mainactivity is of the type ActionBarActivity.

I checked many variants of the code above, but I found no solution. Is there someone, who can help me? I would be happy about a hint, where I can search for and try.

Is it possible that another listener is getting the event? When this can be, how can I find out, which one?

Here's the whole code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static String[] tabellenueberschrift;
public static String[][] tabellenzeilen;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView ueberschrift = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ueberschrift);
    ueberschrift.setText("Beispieltabelle");

    tabellenueberschrift = new String[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        tabellenueberschrift[i] = "Header " + Integer.toString(i);
    }

    tabellenzeilen = new String[3][6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        tabellenzeilen[i][0] = "Zeile " + Integer.toString(i);
        for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
            tabellenzeilen[i][j] = "3";
        }
    }

    TableFixHeaders tableFixHeaders = (TableFixHeaders) findViewById(R.id.table);
    tableFixHeaders.setAdapter(new TableTestAdapter(this));
}
```

**TableTestAdapter.java:**

```
public class TableTestAdapter extends SampleTableAdapter {

private static final String TAG = TableTestAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private final static int WIDTH_DIP = 110;
private final static int HEIGHT_DIP = 48;

private final int width;
private final int height;
public TableTestAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    width = Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, WIDTH_DIP, resources.getDisplayMetrics()));
    height = Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, HEIGHT_DIP, resources.getDisplayMetrics()));
}
@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return 3;
}
@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return 5;
}
@Override
public int getWidth(int column) {
    return width;
}
@Override
public int getHeight(int row) {
    return height;
}
@Override
public String getCellString(int row, int column) {
    if (row == -1) {
        return MainActivity.tabellenueberschrift[column + 1];
    }
    else {
        return MainActivity.tabellenzeilen[row][column + 1];
    }
}
@Override
public int getLayoutResource(int row, int column) {
    final int layoutResource;
    switch (getItemViewType(row, column)) {
        case 0:
            layoutResource = R.layout.tabelle_header;
            break;
        case 1:
            layoutResource = R.layout.tabelle;
            break;
        case 2:
            layoutResource = R.layout.tabelle_spinner;
            break;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("wtf?");
    }
    return layoutResource;
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int row, int column) {
    if (row < 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (column >= 0) {
            return 2;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 3;
}
```

**SampleTableAdapter.java:**

```
public abstract class SampleTableAdapter extends BaseTableAdapter {
private static final String TAG = SampleTableAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private final Context context;
private final LayoutInflater inflater;
/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param context
 * The current context.
 */
public SampleTableAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
/**
 * Returns the context associated with this array adapter. The context is
 * used to create views from the resource passed to the constructor.
 *
 * @return The Context associated with this adapter.
 */
public Context getContext() {
    return context;
}
/**
 * Quick access to the LayoutInflater instance that this Adapter retreived
 * from its Context.
 *
 * @return The shared LayoutInflater.
 */
public LayoutInflater getInflater() {
    return inflater;
}
@Override
public View getView(int row, int column, View converView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (converView == null) {
        converView = inflater.inflate(getLayoutResource(row, column), parent, false);
    }
    if (getItemViewType(row, column) == 2) {
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) converView.findViewById(android.R.id.custom);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getItems(Integer.valueOf(MainActivity.tabellenzeilen[row][column + 1])));
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemSelected()");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onNothingSelected()");
            }
        });

    }
    else {
        setText(converView, getCellString(row, column));
    }
    return converView;
}
/**
 * Sets the text to the view.
 *
 * @param view
 * @param text
 */
private void setText(View view, String text) {
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(text);
}
/**
 * @param row
 * the title of the row of this header. If the column is -1
 * returns the title of the row header.
 * @param column
 * the title of the column of this header. If the column is -1
 * returns the title of the column header.
 * @return the string for the cell [row, column]
 */
public abstract String getCellString(int row, int column);
public abstract int getLayoutResource(int row, int column);

private ArrayList<String> getItems(int anzahl) {
    ArrayList<String> rueckgabe = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < anzahl; i++) {
        rueckgabe.add("Auswahl " + Integer.toString(i+1));
    }

    return rueckgabe;
}
```

Comment: What method are you declaring this code in? Show more code please.

Comment: This code is inside the method getView(int row, int column, View converView, ViewGroup parent) of SampleTableAdapter

Comment: I edited my question above, put in some code and I hope it's helpful to find a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't override getView. Instead you should run your code in onResume to make sure the listener is properly initalized each time the activity comes to front.

Comment: But getView() is inside an adapter, which has no onResume() or something like this. Where I'have to place this in this case?

Comment: Please show your whole code, otherwise all we can do is guess. If you declare your Adapter and set the adapter in one of the Activity life cycle methods your code will work. Your code is correct, but it is in the wrong place.

Comment: I inserted the whole code of an test, which shows the same problem. In logcat there's the message: _W/InputEventReceiver﹕ Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed._